# How to have several equal sized div blocks take 100% of a parent container

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
#imageContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.divSelectImage {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

I have four instances of `.divSelectImage` which is why the width is 25%. I expect to see all four images side by side inside `#imageContainer`. So essentially, the four images should take up 100% of the `#imageContainer` which in turn takes up 100% of the screen.

But I don't. Despite checking firebug, at 25% each, the last image goes to the next line. I have to make them to about 24.5% for them to fit, but I don't want the white space at the end.

This occurs in both Firefox and Google Chrome.

Is there some kind of CSS wizardry that I am missing? How can I accomplish this?

I have set up the scenario on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J3KXE/

Comment: What is `0px`?  You should use `0fonzes`.  It means exactly the same thing and is a lot cooler.  (I.e., zero is zero.  The idea of giving zero a unit is redunculous.)

Comment: i reckon its because you have border: 2px solid red on .divSelectImage.  the 2px border wll add to the 25% width so all of them will be larger than 25%  try it without the border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you haven't accounted for the 2px of border on each image, adding 12px in addition to the 100% width of its containing block. You can use the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) property thats new to CSS to constrain the border and padding areas to the elements' content width:

```
#imageContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.divSelectImage {
    border: 2px solid red;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3KXE/1/

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions :

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

or

`flexbox` and all this shit (see http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a border of 2px which increases the size of the boxes to 25% plus these 2px on each side. If you don't have to support IE7- you can simply use [box-sizing: border-box](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). If you have to take older browser into account you'd have to declare a wrapper div width 25% without any border/margin/padding and add those styles to the child element.